# Join Two Tables With Duplicates

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to combine two peculiar tables in Microsoft Access and have been unable to do so even after doing a lot of brainstorming and searching on the internet.

The two tables are `spend` and `export`

```
Spend   
+-------------+--------+-------+-------+
|     Country | Metal  | Month | Spend |
+-------------+--------+-------+-------+
|     China   | Iron   | Jan   |   100 |
|     China   | Iron   | Feb   |   200 |
|     China   | Iron   | March |   300 |
|     India   | Iron   | Jan   |   400 |
|     India   | Copper | April |   500 |
|     Spain   | Zinc   | June  |   600 |
+-------------+--------+-------+-------+

Export
+-------------+-------+------+--------+
|     Country | Metal | Year | Export |
+-------------+-------+------+--------+
|     China   | Iron  | 2001 | 2,000  |
|     India   | Iron  | 2002 | 4,000  |
|     India   | Iron  | 2003 | 5,000  |
|     Spain   | Zinc  | 2011 | 3,500  |
|     Spain   | Zinc  | 2012 | 4,000  |
|     Spain   | Zinc  | 2013 | 9,000  |
+-------------+-------+------+--------+
```

Desired Combined Table

```
+-------------+--------+-------+-------+------+--------+
|     Country | Metal  | Month | Spend | Year | Export |
+-------------+--------+-------+-------+------+--------+
|     China   | Iron   | Jan   |   100 | 2001 | 2,000  |
|     China   | Iron   | Feb   |   200 |      |        |
|     China   | Iron   | March |   300 |      |        |
|     India   | Iron   | Jan   |   400 | 2002 | 4,000  |
|     India   | Iron   |       |       | 2003 | 5,000  |
|     India   | Copper | April |   500 |      |        |
|     Spain   | Zinc   | June  |   600 | 2011 | 3,500  |
|     Spain   | Zinc   |       |       | 2012 | 4,000  |
|     Spain   | Zinc   |       |       | 2013 | 9,000  |
+-------------+--------+-------+-------+------+--------+
```

Comment: If those are the complete tables, then you're stuck. You won't be able to get the desired output. If you had a `year` column in the `spend` table, then you would be ok. As it is, there is no way to tell that the 2002 Iron export for India is related to the Jan spend of 400. Same problem for the Spain entries..

Comment: Hi Stevie. Thanks. I will be fine even if either of 2002 or 2003 exprt is related to Jan spend of 400 and similarly, for Spain, for June Spend of 600 any of the years can come next to it.

Comment: the point is that you can't have either with your table structure, as the answer you got from Gord demonstrates. What you're seeing in those results aren't duplicates, they're distinct rows according to your schema.

Answer (score 1):

Given your input tables the closest you'll get with a straight Select query is

```sql
SELECT 
    Spend.Country, 
    Spend.Metal, 
    Spend.Month, 
    Spend.Spend, 
    Export.Year, 
    Export.Export
FROM 
    Export 
    RIGHT JOIN 
    Spend 
        ON (Export.Metal = Spend.Metal) 
        AND (Export.Country = Spend.Country)
ORDER BY 
    Spend.Country, 
    Spend.Metal, 
    CDate("2010-" & [Spend].[Month] & "-01"), 
    Export.Year;
```

That query returns

```
Country  Metal   Month  Spend  Year  Export
-------  ------  -----  -----  ----  ------
China    Iron    Jan      100  2001    2000
China    Iron    Feb      200  2001    2000
China    Iron    March    300  2001    2000
India    Copper  April    500              
India    Iron    Jan      400  2002    4000
India    Iron    Jan      400  2003    5000
Spain    Zinc    June     600  2011    3500
Spain    Zinc    June     600  2012    4000
Spain    Zinc    June     600  2013    9000
```

...which includes the rows you specified. However, it does not suppress duplicate Month/Spend and Year/Export values from one row to the next, but that is something that can be done in a report.

Comment: Hi Gordon. Thanks a lot for your help. But, the main issue for me is to avoid duplication of spend and export numbers in my resulting table. Is there any way I can do that? Looking forward to your answer.

Comment: @arpangupta Well, you could convert that query to a Make Table query, create a table containing the results, and then use some VBA looping code to remove the duplicates. However, what will you be doing with these results?